# What to use instead of 'querystring'? 'node:querystring' or URLSearchParams for NodeJS application (Node Version 16.15)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

Our current application (running on Node 16.15) gives below error/warning for ('querystring') package version 0.2.1.

[image]

When I import the 'querystring' package as

```
const qs = require('node:querystring')
```

The error/warning (sliced 'qs') is no more.
Hower as per above snip, it asks me to use URLSearchParams.

Which ones is the proper/feasible/reliable way to use?

Comment: decode/encodeURIComponent

Comment: I am using parse() and stringify() of 'querystring'

Comment: URLSearchParams

Comment: Okay, I will give it a try. Do you have any documentation or blogs which show the transformation of this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Comment: if it is a legacy code no need to transform the whole code according to latest specification, querystring isn't worse.